# App crash when use nstask with sandbox

Tags: sandbox, nstask

I used this code in my app:

```
//create task
NSTask * task=[[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/ps"];
NSArray * arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"axco command,pcpu",nil];
[task setArguments:arguments];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];

NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
[task launch];
```

When I disable the sandbox, it works. But if I enable the sandbox, it crashes with this exception:

> NSTask: Task create for path '/bin/ps' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Take a look in Console to view if there are some sandbox messages

Comment: I don't see anything else sandbox messages. My app is crash and print only message in console: NSTask: Task create for path '/bin/ps' failed: 22, "Invalid argument". Terminating temporary process. Please give me details your solutions. Thanks very much